# Get Screen size without keyboard size

Tags: android

I have to set Dropdown list above the soft keyboard.While scrolling its appearing above the keyboard. How can i get window or device size except soft keyboard height ? Is there any way to do this? 
Thanx in advanced !!!

Answer (score 3):

When the keyboard is launched the view hierarchy is invalidated and re-drawn. So you can use this callback:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
      //
     }
});
```

The height including keyboard can be retrieved with:

```
activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight()
```

The height of your view resized by the soft keyboard:

```
activityRootView.getHeight()
```

Comment: using this, I am getting different value of height every time .

Comment: for both activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() and activityRootView.getHeight() ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame%28android.graphics.Rect%29) method of the root view group to get the size of the visible frame